# Google Street View API: Disable changing position by double-clicking

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am using the Google Street view API and want to disable all of the controls besides panning and zooming. If you click or double click it will change your position to that location. Right now I am using the 'position_changed' event to check if the user changed the position and then try to reset the position to the original. It's a hack but its all I have found possible. The problem I am having is I get in an infinite loop.

```
        var origPosY = panorama.getPosition().Ya,
            origPosX = panorama.getPosition().Za,
            originalPos = new google.maps.LatLng(panorama.getPosition().Ya, panorama.getPosition().Za);

        google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
            //console.log('Position changed',panorama.getPosition().Ya, panorama.getPosition().Za);
            //var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(panorama.getPosition().Ya, panorama.getPosition().Za);
            if( origPosY != panorama.getPosition().Ya ){
                console.log('Resetting pos');
                panorama.setPosition(originalPos); 
            }

        });
```

It appears that when I check to make sure they are different it is still getting inside the if statement. Does anyone know of any other way to disable this functionality? They let you disable all the controls but not the double-click and mouse wheel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the options `clickToGo` and `scrollwheel` of `panorama` to `false`

Comment: Thank you this works! How is this not listed anywhere else??? Thanks again I tried to vote but do not have enough reputation.

Comment: it's listed inside the api-documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#StreetViewPanoramaOptions